# How to say "I don't even want to bother with it"?

Tags: translation, verb

I don't even want to use any translators.

So, I made up something like this:

> Ich sogar nicht will, um mit das die Mühe.

Is it correct? I couldn't find anything useful enough about *to bother* on the Internet. Is there a version with *bother* as a verb?

UPDATE:
To make the question clearer, I would like to describe a situation. Let's assume you have a spot on your shirt, but it is so tiny that it can hardly be spotted. But some of your friends spotted it though and then they point it out. And that is such a minor issue that you would respond like:

> I don't even want to bother with it, I have much more important stuff to do.

Comment: _[[Das] ist] mir doch egal._  ‘I don’t care.’ / _[Das/es] stört/juckt mich nicht [die Bohne]._ ‘I can’t be bothered by it.’ / _Phh._ ‘Meh.’

Comment: Don't worry. Just keep working on questions with the help of reviewers. Many people revise their votes!

Comment: Your first sentence... Not sure what you want to convey, but it doesn't do you a world of good. It sounds like: "I don't want to put any effort into this, so I quickly made something up and posted it here and you guys can now help me get this right". Perhaps, you should remove the part before your example altogether.

Comment: [bother on leo][http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=bother&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on] Does that help in any way? As is, the question needs to be closed two days ago.

Comment: I have just asked a native German speaker, who leaved in US for 1 year. He had understand the sentence "I don't want to bother with it". He was thinking how to translate it, so gave him an example. He immediately gave an answer: "Das kümmert mich nicht". He said that Germans just don't say in such way.

Comment: to Em1. I have put a lot of effort in searching the way how to translate it. And I have not found what I searching for. Your statement is funny though

Comment: "Das kümmert mich nicht" is correct, but you would find it rather in older fiction (some novel or so), not in today's everyday communication. It is a little bit too high-level in terms of style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical phrase in German, for the situation you describe, would be:

> Nicht der Rede wert!

(informal language, as in private conversation), or

> Das ist doch nicht der Rede wert.

(which is slightly more formal, like written in a novel)

Even more casually you may say:

> Ach komm, ist doch wurscht!

or shorter

> Wurscht!

or in southern dialect:

> 'sch mir wurscht

which in standard German translates "Ist mir wurscht", but sounds very similar to "Schmierwurst" which again is a casual word for meat paste. Which has no deeper meaning here at all, it is just an ironic pun. (The '"sch mir wurscht" thing may be common only in certain sub-groups of the German speaking population.)

The shortest and most common way to express it would simply be

> Ach, egal!

or only

> Egal!

Finally, here one more phrase you would most probably find in fiction, not in everyday communication:

> Sei's drum.

("Be it as it is")

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your sentence, but it is going into the right direction.

It would be something like:

> Ich will mir so gar nicht die Mühe machen/nehmen.

*Sogar* means *even*, as in "He even made me laugh".

*So gar nicht* means *so not*, *so absolutely not* or better *by no means*.

*Die Mühe nehmen* means *take up the burden*, *bother*, *to give an extra effort*.

The whole sentence could be translated:

> I have no intention whatsoever to take up this burden.

If you just want future tense and not so much volition and tone it down a little, it would be:

> Ich werde mir keine Mühe geben.

But this has the connotation of unwillingness to go the extra mile or give your best. Just as the first one.

If you want to express something like "I will not even give you an answer for this", you could say:

> Ich werde das jetzt nicht einmal beachten.

*To bother* can be translated *sich bemühen*.

> Ich werde mich nicht bemühen. - I will not bother.
>
> Ich werde Dich nicht bemühen. - I will not bother you, ask anything of you.
>
> Ich will Dich nicht nerven, stören, belästigen. - I do not want to bother you (get on your nerves).

You can see it here: [leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Bother&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on).

Comment: Ich habe "sich die Mühe nehmen" noch nie gehört. "sich die Mühe machen" (oder alternativ "die Mühe auf sich nehmen") scheint mir bei weitem gebräuchlicher zu sein.

Comment: I will let the OP decide, but personally, I find the structure of this answer somewhat confusing. For instance, why is "so gar nicht" suggested in the beginning, when it is correctly explained in the further course of the answer that is has little to nothing to do with "sogar" + "nicht" (as the inverse of "sogar" is "nicht einmal")? In that respect, stating "It would be something like:" for the sentence with "so gar nicht" is rather misleading.

Comment: Also, while the third example with "bother" is correct, I am not convinced of the other two ones. To me, "sich bemühen" still carries the meaning suggest for "sich Mühe geben", as suggested by you, of going the extra mile. While I cannot pinpoint a hard rule there, in my personal feeling, the major difference is that "Ich werde mich [nicht] bemühen." sounds simply strange as long as it is missing something like an object, such as "Ich werde mich [nicht] darum bemühen." or "Ich werde mich dabei [nicht] bemühen.", unlike "Ich werde mir [keine] Mühe geben.", but maybe that is something regional.

Comment: Could you please check the update and revise the answer? I have never seen any of construction with Mühe. So maybe, my suggestion is totally wrong

Comment: I agree with @O.R.Mapper. But since the question has been updated, it's worth amending the answer anyway. I think it make sense to remove most of it and instead refer to the example that was added to the question.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Regarding your edit: It's correct to say to "get on somebody's nerves", with plural.